# Get columns from two tabels with fallback value

Tags: mysql, select, left-join, multiple-tables, fallback

I'm currently trying to fetch an object from one table with global stats including it's daily stats from a second table. For this I use the following join-query that works intended as long as the statsTable contains a matching row for both '`oID`' and '`Date`' columns.

```
SELECT
  o.ID as ID,
  o.Image as Image,
  o.Text as `Text`,
  o.Views as `Views`,
  o.Clicks as Clicks,
  COALESCE(s.Views, 0) as DayViews,
  COALESCE(s.Clicks, 0) as DayClicks
FROM objectTable o
LEFT JOIN statsTable s
ON o.ID = s.oID
WHERE o.userID = 1
  AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), s.Date) < 1
LIMIT 1
```

How do I have to change the query to get a result row even if statsTable does not contain a matching row?

The query does not give errors, I just do not want it to return an empty result as I know for sure that there are data in objectTable.

Comment: you have already use left join. it is the ans. please check without where condition

Comment: as I already said, yes: the left join works **if** statsTable has data to join. But I want a result even if no data are available. What should I use instead of  `Where`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to move the condition on the `s` table into the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT o.ID as ID, o.Image as Image, o.Text as `Text`,
       o.Views as `Views`, o.Clicks as Clicks,
       COALESCE(s.Views, 0) as DayViews,
       COALESCE(s.Clicks, 0) as DayClicks
FROM objectTable o LEFT JOIN
     statsTable s
     ON o.ID = s.oID AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), s.Date) < 1
WHERE o.userID = 1 ;
```

A `LEFT JOIN` keeps all rows in the first table, regardless of whether the `ON` clause evaluates to true or not.  The columns in the second table are `NULL` for non-matching rows -- which the `WHERE` clause then filters out.

As a result, conditions on the *first* table should be in the `WHERE` clause.  Conditions on subsequent tables should be in the `ON` clause -- for a `LEFT JOIN`.